# How to safe copy Angular project to another computer?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular project on my desktop. But I want to move/copy my current Angular project to my laptop computer the whole things.

- On my laptop the NodeJS, TypeScript and Angular are installed.

I just to want backup my project from desktop to laptop by just run

```
npm install
```

and

```
ng serve
```

to continue my job. As well.

Comment: So just move the folders. I'm not sure what the question is

Comment: Upload your project to github. Then clone the project to your laptop. [Helpful Github Url](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

1. the best way to keep your project safe use GitHub or bitbucket
2. if you simply want to copy your project to another system then zip the project without node_module and then copy paste.